# How to change a cell value for Excel Visual Basic for x variable in the same row?

Tags: vba, excel

I was making function for userform in Excel Visual basic, that change specific cell value for a X selected for one column. However, each time the user change value in the userform created, the program multiply the data in each cell related to that column and X value. Example: In case I have in column "A" the value Marie three times, one in the row 3, 7, 10 and my userform input for column "B" is hello. The output for each row will be the same "hello". But I want to modify each value independently the values column "A" repeated.

**The code for the userform:**

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")

lastrow = Sheets("Table").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
count = 0
For x = 2 To lastrow


If Sheets("Table").Cells(x, 1) = Me.cmbEmp Then 
ws.Cells(x, 3) = Me.ldlcolor
ws.Cells(x, 30) = (Me.ldlp)
count = count + 1

End If
If Sheets("Table").Cells(x, 3) = Me.cmbEmp Then 
ws.Cells(x, 1) = Me.ldlname
ws.Cells(x, 14) = (Me.ldlI)
count = count + 1
End If

Next x

Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are looping through every row of your sheet, and if a value is duplicated on different rows, it will match each time. You will need to come up with a better way of determining which of the duplicate values you want to modify. For example, this code will loop through until it finds the FIRST occurrence of your data ("marie"):

```
Dim bolFound As Boolean
bolFound = False
While Not bolFound
    If Sheets("Table").Cells(x, 1) = Me.cmbEmp Then 
        ws.Cells(x, 3) = Me.ldlcolor
        ws.Cells(x, 30) = (Me.ldlp)
        count = count + 1
        bolFound = True
    End If

    If Sheets("Table").Cells(x, 3) = Me.cmbEmp Then 
        ws.Cells(x, 1) = Me.ldlname
        ws.Cells(x, 14) = (Me.ldlI)
        count = count + 1
        bolFound = True
    End If
Wend
```

If you don't know which occurrence of "marie" you want to change, then you either have to remove duplicate data or figure out a way to differentiate the "marie" on row 3 vs the "marie on row 7.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your code, but it make an infinite loop then the program crash.

Comment: I just solved the problem, thanks man. I found a way to dofferentiate the name XD